# Duplicate instances of "no-store" header in response

Tags: java, spring, caching, httpresponse, cache-control

I was trying to set response headers to my spring project. I wanted to set Cache-Control to "no-cache , no-store" . However , two instances of no-store are getting appended to cache-control header. Any reason from where the second instance is coming? I have checked the backend code to see if there is another place where this property is being set, but that is not the case.

This is the cache control entry im getting :
Cache-Control="no-cache, no-store,no-store"